# How to setup batch fetching for history entities using nhibernate.envers

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

Can one setup batch size for fetching as per `19.1.5` (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch)
only for historic entities? I cannot find an option, but maybe someone ever stumbled upon this problem and could guide me in a right direction, if its even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not currently supported.